# How validation rules work in laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4, short-circuiting

In laravel, in order to validate some input from user, we can use Validator Class.

for example for a registration by email , validation rule can be:

```
array( 'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email' )
```

Which says, email is required, email should be in email format, and should not registered in table `users` before. ( should be unique )

So, How does this work?

Does it use **[short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)** ? If we go through step by step

- it checks if input is set by `required`
  if Passed, jumps to next rule
- then checks if it is in email format
  if Passed, jumps to next rule
- checks if not exists in table `users`

I asked someone and he said , it check all , goes through all rules.
If `required` rule is not passed, there is no reason to check if input is in email format.
And if it is not in email format, there is no need to check database.

Does anyone know how it work?

Comment: Did you checked out and tried to understand the source of the validation class? The files are located in the `vendor/laravel/src/Illuminate/Validation` folder.

Comment: If one required field is failed and Laravel stop checking rest of the rules, Now, how do you know rest of the required fields are valid and show error messages.

Comment: for example: if an email input not even filled and submitted, why you should report to user: hey email format error!!!, seems a bit silly, it should report to user: hey email is required!! this question is about all rules for one user input. not all user inputs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on the rule.  In practice, Laravel will stop processing other rules if the `required` attribute is failed.  However, if `required` passes, it will continue to validate other rules.

This means you can receive multiple Validation Errors on the same field.

Answer (score 3):

I could not find details for Laravel 4, but the [Laravel 5.4 documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation) implies that all validation rules are run in order without short-circuit evaluation.

In Laravel 5, you can force short-circuit evaluation by prefixing 'bail' to the validation rule.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'bail|required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
]);
```

I came here looking for why short-circuiting would be off by default, I think James is correct in his reasoning that it is for receiving multiple validation errors on the same field.